# Where START command on Windows finds the path to executable

Tags: windows, shell, command

I would like to know where `START` command on Windows finds the path to executable. For example, if I run `START /W  python` and have no path to `python.exe` in my `PATH` environment variable it correctly finds the path and runs python. In my system it is `C:\Python27\python.exe` So, how `START` finds the correct path?

P.S.
If I write python via my command prompt (`cmd.exe`) it can not find the path to python.

Thank you!

Comment: Like any other command: through the `PATH`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have no path to python executable in my `PATH`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `START` command from command line or batch file, or when you use the `Run` dialog, the systems follows the behaviour documented for `ShellExecute` or `ShellExecuteEx` API calls.

In general, the application will be searched in:

1. The current working directory.
2. The Windows directory.
3. The Windows\System32 directory.
4. Directories listed in the PATH environment variable.
5. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
6. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\ApplicationName.exe

For a complete description read [Application Registration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx)